# Loading class through Jars in scala

Tags: scala, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I am trying to load a class from target Jar, I saw some examples and tried to replicate, but unfortunately i couldn't.

What am I doing wrong here:

```
import java.io.File
import java.net.{URL, URLClassLoader}

  val jarPathName = "C:\\Users\\Pedro Luis\\IdeaProjects\\Metamorphosis\\test\\typeLoader\\testJars\\DummySimpleClass3.jar"

  val classLoader = new URLClassLoader(Array[URL](new File(jarPathName).toURI.toURL))
  val classToLoad = classLoader.loadClass("DummySimpleClass.scala")
  val method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("printer")
  val instance = classToLoad.newInstance()

  method.invoke(instance)
```

The class that is inside of jar is the following:

```
package typeLoader.testJars

class DummySimpleClass {

  def printer(): Unit = println("Hello World!")

}
```

And the error that I got is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.typeLoader.testJars.DummySimpleClass.scala
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at efeawfew.JavaTest$.<init>(JavaTest.scala:13)
```

Any ideas?

[image]
Edited: Added the jar path

Comment: The jar file need to contain the compiled class in a directory structure that matches the package hierarchy. In the your image, there is only the source file in the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot, your JAR file is not valid, it contains `.scala` file. Actual JAR file must contain `.class` file.

Comment: It seems that I cannot load Scala classes like this, only works with .class as you mentioned, ty

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention the package name as well

```
 import java.io.File
import java.net.{URL, URLClassLoader}

  val jarPathName = "C:\\Users\\Pedro Luis\\IdeaProjects\\Metamorphosis\\test\\typeLoader\\testJars\\DummySimpleClass3.jar"

  val classLoader = new URLClassLoader(Array[URL](new File(jarPathName).toURI.toURL))
  val classToLoad = classLoader.loadClass("typeLoader.testJars.DummySimpleClass.scala")
  val method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("printer")
  val instance = classToLoad.newInstance()

  method.invoke(instance)
```

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís Check the path `...DummySimpleClass3.jar` and that it's a valid JAR (not sure about spaces in path in Windows). Class name should be without `scala`: `classLoader.loadClass("typeLoader.testJars.DummySimpleClass")`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin the jar is valid and is there, and the class with that name doesn´t work either, any more ideas? :)